# Issues in Configuring SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 for Https

Tags: content-porter-2009, https

I have recently configured our SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 server to use Https instead of Http, there were many issues some of them I was able to get around however following are the two issues which I am still facing.

1. Content Porter does not work
2. template builder is also not working.

Following is the error which I am receiving

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.296
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : ImportExportService/Client/cp.application

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of ImportExportService/Client/cp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading ImportExportService/Client/cp.application did not succeed.
    + The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
    + The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [02/04/2013 17:36:33] : Activation of ImportExportService/Client/cp.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [02/04/2013 17:36:33] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading ImportExportService/Client/cp.application did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
    - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
        at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
        at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
        at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
        at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

It seems that this error might be because I am using a local certificate,

Any pointers will be great.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: It looks like you are getting problem even when downloading the CP or Template Builder tool from Tools menu of CME, or are you getting the error while really connecting using TB or CP?
Please elaborate what actually you mean by "Does Not Work"

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the stack trace, I see "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

The client computer you are trying to run the Template Builder and Content Porter from needs to trust the SSL certificate presented by the Content Manager.

If you access the Content Manager site from the client computer using Internet Explorer, do you get prompted about the certificate?  If so then the certificate is untrusted, you will need to trust it before Template Builder and Content Porter will work.